# Count within a count

Tags: sql, oracle, count

REVISED:
Okay, thanks to all of your input, I figured out what I was doing wrong (sorry guys). I am grabbing the courseID which counts as a section NOT an actual course.  For me to grab the actual courseName, I have to go over to the Course Table.

So now I have StudentID from Enrollment and CourseNum from Course that need to be used to count.  I'll try and work with what you guys have provided to see if I can come up with the results.

EDIT:
Here's my revised SQL. This provides me with the total courses for each student. I'm getting there:

```
SELECT     Count(DISTINCT Course.courseNum), Grades.studentID
FROM         Grades INNER JOIN
             Course ON Grades.courseID = Course.courseID
             GROUP BY Grades.studentID;
```

Final Code just in case those who care:

```
SELECT COUNT(NumCourses) FROM 
(SELECT     Count(DISTINCT Course.courseNum)AS NumCourses
FROM         Grades INNER JOIN
                      Course ON Grades.courseID = Course.courseID
                     GROUP BY Grades.studentID
           HAVING Count(DISTINCT Course.courseNum) = 1) a;
```

Comment: You just need to add an inner join to the courses table & perform the having clause on that table.

Comment: You should accept an answer if you feel your question has been answered.

Comment: And you should use the voting system.

Comment: The final code doesn't do what you initially asked for: return those who are on 4 course. What happened to that? Your final query can also be optimized a bit.

Comment: I fixed it.  It's suppose to be count instead of sum. I tested with 1 because I knew how many students were exactly in one course.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total number of students on 4+ courses, this is the SQL:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CourseCount) AS CourseCount
FROM    (
    SELECT  StudentID, COUNT(CourseID) AS CourseCount
            FROM enrollment
            GROUP BY StudentID
            HAVING  (COUNT(CourseID) >= 4)) AS T
```

It is much simpler to get the student count using a second query.

Comment: This looks to do the trick. I had to remove the AS T at the end though.

Comment: Scratch that. I removed the >= 4 replaced with =4 and it gave me 4.

Comment: >=4 will give you students who are on 4 or more courses. 4 will give you only 4. You pick. Either way, this is the correct code to give you the results you want.

Comment: I only need students with 4 courses.  Why will it only give me 4?

Comment: How many students do you have with 4 unique course IDs in your enrollments table? This query is simply counting the number of CourseIDs per StudentID. If it says 4, then there must only be 4 students who have 4 courses.

Comment: Based on other answers, some of which are correct, and your responses, I believe you have a problem with your enrollments table data. There is no bug in this query I gave you.

Comment: I agree with you.  I generated queries like everyone else's, but it also gave me an incorrect value. I will take a look to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ps. I see you're new to StackOverflow. We have a tradition of voting for helpful answers ;)

Comment: I have revised my question above.  I'm going to see if I can work it out using everyone's code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select count(studentId), count(courseId) from enrolment group by courseId having (count(courseId) = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enrollment 
     GROUP BY studentid HAVING COUNT(*) = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(NumCourses) AS NumStudents, NumCourses FROM (SELECT COUNT(courseID) AS NumCourses FROM enrollment GROUP BY courseID HAVING COUNT(courseID) = 4) As SomeTableAlias
```

Comment: Try it now. I removed the line breaks. I just tried the query again and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. It works fine for me on MySQL. Oracle might need some slight modifications to the query format.

Comment: Removed the AS at the end, and it gives me numStudents 4 NumCourses 4.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you wanted the number of students who are enrolled in exactly four courses.
If you want to count the number of students and the number of courses, do this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumStudents FROM (SELECT DISTINCT studendid FROM enrollment)), (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumCourses FROM (SELECT DISTINCT courseid FROM enrollment))
```

Comment: You are correct. I need the number of students who are enrolled in exactly four classes.

Comment: So my first solution and the one of sh_kamalh (which is identical), should do the trick. If you just get 3 as a result but expected 190, there could be something wrong with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
  from (select student_id from enrollment group by student_id having count(*) = 4)
```

The inner query gives you the IDs of the students who enrolled in exactly 4 courses then I count them.